# Reduce postgresql update statement to one line

Tags: sql, postgresql

**How can I reduce the following update-statmenents to one?**

E.g with an IF-Clause:

```
  UPDATE users SET registered_at = now() WHERE id = new.id AND status = 'completed';
  UPDATE users SET registered_at = NULL WHERE id = new.id AND status != 'completed';
```

**Thanks**

Comment: Use a `case` expression!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `case` expression:

```
UPDATE users
SET registered_at = case when status = 'completed' then now() end
WHERE id = new.id
```

`ELSE NULL` is default, so you don't have to specify that part of the `case` expression.